# AsyncImageView not caching the image

Tags: objective-c, ios, caching, uiimageview, image-caching

Um using `AsyncImageView` class [here](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView). In the documentation they are saying that "By default, all loaded images are cached". You can see it at the last paragraph in the documentation.

But **the problem** is when I try to load the images again it comes with the placeholder and wait a few seconds to load the image from URL again even it has been loaded successfully last time.

That means it wasn't cached, right ?
So um asking if there a problem with my code ?
Why the images not been cached like using the `SDWebImage` ?

These is my code :

```
AsyncImageView *imageView = [[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, productCellWidth, productCellHeight)];
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
NSURL *URL =  [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:ProductPicture]];
[AsyncImageLoader defaultCache];
[[AsyncImageLoader sharedLoader]loadImageWithURL:URL target:self success:@selector(successSelector) failure:@selector(failureSelector)];
```

Comment: "the cache will keep building up until a memory warning is triggered". Have you triggered a memory warning?

Answer (score 1):

there is another library I used it before and it working well
this library called "[SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)" you can use it simply by a method:

```
[imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.domain.com/path/to/image.jpg"]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

and it cache images automatically and it support loading only from cache (if you need).

Comment: Ok Um using it right now and it working great but how to tell it the time to cache, meaning If I want to clear the cache ?
I want to cache new images each 4 days, So I want it to call the server each 4 days, how to set these property ?

Answer (score 1):

in SDImageCache.m you will find this line of code:

```
static NSInteger cacheMaxCacheAge = 60*60*24*7; // 1 week
```

it's the cached image lifetime you can change it to 4 days instead of 7 days

Comment: Or You can call [SDWebImageCache.sharedImageCache clearDisk] every 4 days

Answer (score 0):

to me your code looks wrong. you just set imageURL of the AsyncImageView.

You dont deal with the loader

Answer (score -2):

I've solved this problem: you need to add

```
#import "AsyncImageView.h"
```

in your file .m

and USE

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:yourUrlString];
photo.imageURL = url;
```

OR FOR EXAMPLE

```
cell.imageView.imageURL = url;
```

and NOT

```
UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
photo.image = theImage;
```